# What path for wkhtmltoimage for Windows and local server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, path, wkhtmltoimage

I am running rails on a local server on windows.
I installed wkhtmltoimage to C:/Sites/wkhtmltoimage

Now I have to tell IMGKit where to find it, so I added a file initializers/imgkit.rb:

```
IMGKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltoimage = 'C:/Sites/wkhtmltoimage'
end
```

But When I try to use IMGKit, rails tells me:

```
No wkhtmltoimage executable found at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
```

But I set up a new path for it ?

I tried to require this file to be sure it is loaded

```
require 'config/initializers/imgkit.rb'
```

But then I get told:
cannot load such file -- config/initializers/imgkit.rb

What do I have to do now ? Please help.

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I'm having similar issues.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am sorry.
Concerning people changed servers later .. maybe it worked then.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put full path with .exe like this:

```
config.wkhtmltoimage = 'C:/Sites/wkhtmltoimage/bin/wkhtmltoimage.exe'
```

and add this path: 'C:/Sites/wkhtmltoimage/bin/' to PATH in your environmental variables.

Then you should see the wkhtmltoimage globally.